# Javascript Regex ##x##

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex that pulls out the format from a string.

Take this example, "5x7 (+$50)" or "20x24 (+70)". Is there any easier way to pull out the ##x## or #x#?

Here's the current code example....As you'll see the substring doesn't necessarily work for all test cases.

```
var example = "5x7 ($50)";
var ex_arr = example.split("x");

console.log(ex_arr[0]);
console.log(ex_arr[1].substring(0, 2));
```

Comment: Could just `.match(/(\d+)x(\d+)/)`

Comment: If there's always a space between them, just split again on space, and get the first value.

Comment: `ex_arr[1].split(/\s/).shift()`

Comment: I'm gonna go with @Niet the Dark Absol on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\d+)x(\d+)\s.*$
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: http://www.rexfiddle.net/RkUvHCK

Capture 1 is the first number, Capture 2 is the second number. Everything else is discarded.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Indeed, it could be shortened to `^(\d+)x(\d+)\s` or even `^(\d+)x(\d+)` if it suits the asker's needs, but I like to be thorough. :)